# Is a (pseudoinverse) tag ok?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I tagged [a question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1034210/163) [pseudoinverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudoinverse), but it got removed. Since a pseudoinverse is about matrices/operators that are not necessarily invertible, [inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inverse) is not exactly adequate, so I'd prefer adding this new tag. But I don't want to start an edit war (especially across at least [79 questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=pseudoinverse+is%3Aquestion) that might deserve it) so I'd rather hear community consensus first:

> Is it ok to tag questions about pseudoinverses [pseudoinverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudoinverse)?

Proposed tag-excerpt and tag-wiki can be found in a **Community Wiki** answer below.

Comment: I'll point out that some users do not like the ([tag:inverse]) tag either and it was suggested to [delete that tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/2747#2747).

Comment: It is recommended that a person who creates a new tag also creates tag-wiki or at least tag-excerpt explaining what the tag is intended for. (See, for example, [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17023/should-every-new-tag-be-discussed-on-meta-before-creation/17025#17025).) Could you add to your post proposed tag-excerpt to your post here on meta? (Or if you created the tag-info back then, you could at least add a link to your suggested edit, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242090/).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ok, added. I wouldn't call the opposition to [tag:inverse] that overwhelming judging from the little attention that answer got, and deleting that tag would really be counter-productive IMHO.

Comment: I do believe that is too long (an "formatty") for a _tag-excerpt_, but might make a reasonable _tag-wiki_. Since the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse is only one kind of pseudoinverse, you might consider using instead either (matrix-pseudoinverses) (to be more general) or (moore-penrose-pseudoinverse) (to be more precise). Also important information for the excerpt/wiki includes under which circumstances the tag _should_ be used, and edge cases where it _should not_.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Thanks, I added an excerpt. I'd rather leave the tag as [tag:pseudoinverse] and include other potential meanings in its wiki. If a matrix is concerned, the tag [tag:matrices] should be added anyway, and the other pseudoinverses occur so rarely that a tag-diversification would IMHO be overkill.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to move the proposed tag-excerpt/-wiki to a CW answer, so as to not clutter the question itself.

Comment: @ArthurFischer good point, thanks

Comment: Noticing your yesterday's activity, I would point out that it is better not to do too many retags of old questions at the same time. See older discussion [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6200/editing-binge-etiquette) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/how-much-bumping-is-too-much?). (But since nobody complained, the number of your edits was probably ok.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Actually I got a polite mod-message regarding that... I guess a "You've edited 20 posts in the last 5 minutes, please don't overdo it" warning might be useful...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Proposed tag-excerpt:

> The operator $A^+$ which best approximates a solution to linear equations $Ax+b=0$ even if $A$ is singular.

### Proposed tag-wiki:

(Based on the Wikipedia entry)

> ### Pseudoinverse
>
> #### (also "Generalized Inverse")
>
> For linear operators and matrices that are not invertible there still exists a unique [Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) $A^+$ which fulfils the following conditions:
>
> - $A A^+A = A$
>     ($AA^+$ need not be the general identity matrix, but it maps all column vectors of $A$ to themselves);
> - $A^+A A^+ = A^+$
>     ($A^+$ is a [weak inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_inverse) for the multiplicative semigroup);
> - $(AA^+)^* = AA^+$
>     ($AA^+$ is Hermitian); and
> - $(A^+A)^* = A^+A$
>     ($A^+A$ is also Hermitian).
>
> Use it: when the Matrix/Operator involved is (probably) singular
>
> Don't use it: when the Matrix/Operator is definitely invertible or its state is unknown

Comment: Lacking objections I guess it's ok...

Comment: The tag excerpt should specify that the "best approximation" is in the $\|Ax-b\|_2$-sense. Also I've seen (and use myself) the notation $A^\dagger$ (`\dagger`). This might be worth mentioning in the tag wiki.

Comment: My only objection is that it seems to conflate the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse with the concept of a generalized inverse, which needs only to satisfy the first of the Penrose conditions.